# Error reading JSONP in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, jsfiddle

I am trying to run with success the example in http://jsfiddle.net/srlopez/zXPSB/4/

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
$http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: 'https://212.142.196.44/cardiopen/episodio/list/2'
}).
success(function (data, status) {
    console.log('data:', data);
}).
error(function (data, status) {
    console.log('status:', status);
    console.log('data:', data);
});
```

}

It reads a JSON from that url but always get error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 212.142.196.44/cardiopen/episodio/list/2
status: 0 
data: undefined

And the url is ok.
Can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

Just use the shorthand method:

```
$http.jsonp('https://212.142.196.44/cardiopen/episodio/list/2').then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Adding .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
      }); I have the same error